# Make Semantic UI search selection drop down scroll to selected item on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am working with the Semantic UI searchable dropdown, which if you're not familiar with it, it can be found here: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-selection.

How would I make it so that once an item is selected in the dropdown, that when you click out and click back in, it would show the currently selected item at the top of the list? So scroll to the selected/active item?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Semantic UI you're using? 'Cause the default behavior of Semantic UI search selection dropdown is just fine.

```js
$('.ui.search.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<select class="ui search dropdown">
  <option value="">State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Interesting that this works. I am utilizing the div method vs using a select with options. I am using Semantic 2.1.8 actually and it scrolls down only when you click on the arrow there. I am also pulling the data in remotely to do this.